# Get business name from CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, cllocation, clgeocoder, clplacemark

I'm trying to get the business name from a `CLLocation`. I am able to get the exact street address by reverse geocoding the `CLLocation`, but am unable to get the name of the business, as the `name` property on `CLPlacemark` is just the address.

I have tried:

- Accessing the `name` property on `CLPlacemark`: **returns street address**
- Accessing the `areasOfInterest` property on `CLPlacemark`: **returns nil**
- Using `MKLocalSearchCompleter` with the query set to the street address **returns street address**
- Using `MKLocalSearch` with the query set to the street address **returns nothing**

What's strange is that the Apple Maps app allows you to search for the street address and the business name will come up for most locations (and use the address as a fallback, [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRlr5.jpg)), but I cannot replicate this feature with the exposed API's. Is what I'm wanting simply not possible with MapKit?

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error ) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks else {
                fatalError("Error: failed to reverse geocode location. \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }


            for placemark in placemarks {
                print(placemark.name)
            }

            // Do something to get the *true* placemark name.
        })
```

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566325/looking-for-business-name-information-from-coordinates-using-cllocation-and-or-m and similar